# why do i have a date error in my sql query?

Tags: db2

I am doing an SQL SELECT query but I have the error message:

> "SQL Error [22007]: [SQL0181] A value of date, time, or timestamp
>   string is incorrect."

Here is my request:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM ROXDTA400.STKF0300 A 
 JOIN ROXDTA400.TABJ00141 B ON A.STNSIT = B.CDSITE 
 WHERE ( A.STNLIB <> '-- Trémie --' 
         AND A.STNSIT <> 40 
         AND DATE(LEFT(STNDAV,4) || '-' || substr(STNDAV,5,2) || '-' || RIGHT(STNDAV,2)) 
         BETWEEN  DATE('2019-01-01') AND DATE('2019-01-04')  );
```

The problem seems to come from the date created with the STNDAV field, because if I replace with for example DATE ('2019-01-03'), it works.
DATE (LEFT (STNDAV, 4) || '-' || substr (STNDAV, 5,2) || '-' || RIGHT (STNDAV, 2)) Gives me the correct date format.

Where would the problem come from?

thank you,

Comment: Assuming STNDAV is a CHAR/VARCHAR datatype containing YYYYMMDD values, you will get this symptom if the data in at least one row is not valid (contains characters that don't comply with YYYYMMDD).

Comment: Also if STNDAV is longer than 8 characters, the RIGHT(STNDAV,2) may not return what you expect, compare substr(STNDAV,7,2).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I understood what I wanted, it's not what I mean between two dates and not show others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that dates stored in STNDAV are valid.  I mean, check there is any invalid date such as February 30th or '99999999'.  If the source is an IBM i (iSeries or AS/400), it will be faster if you avoid functions in the WHERE portion, so STNDAV BETWEEN '20190101' AND '20190104' will perform better.

Comment: Actually almost every DB go faster with no functions in a where clause or join clause